# facebook like/follow api enforcing clicking like button twice

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Here is my code:

```
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : 'xxxxxxx',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v2.9'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
            // fired after like has fulfilled
        });
      };
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="fb-like" href="https://www.facebook.com/xxx" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false"/>
```

Whats occurring is when I load the like/follow button the user clicks once, if your logged in **it enforces you** to `immediately click like again after clicking like already once`, else it asks you to login `and then enforce to hit the like button again.`

**My question is why can't I just click the like once, and if im logged in it then likes instead of me having to click again, else if during a login then it logs you in and then immediately records as a like clicked.**

I've seen implementations around that have this workflow. **Maybe theres something wrong with my API Code**

**UPDATE**

So, i added a `status:true` flag to the `init` and it seemed to resolve the issue when the user is logged in and requiring to `like twice`. **However**, when i have to login then it **asks me again to like after i login**. Shouldn't it automatically like it once i login and **not have to click like again**.

Comment: _“if your logged in it asks you to immediately click like again after clicking like already once”_ - how is it “asking” you for that? Does an actual message appear, saying “Please click the Like button again, immediately” - or what are you actually talking about …?

Comment: @CBroe I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried initializing the SDK with `status: true`, to instruct it to check the current login status?

Comment: @CBroe That helped the situation when I'm logged in, however if I'm not logged in it requires me to login then asks to like again. How do I make it so after I login it automatically likes me, or is that some policy that facebook implemented? I see this action available on other sites where they login and then it doesnt ask you again. Just not sure whats going on here.

Comment: @CBroe any input would be highly appreciated. im not quite sure how to resolve this issue and you seem to know a thing or two about this.

Comment: I don’t know, can just recommend that you compare the implementation of those other sites you are talking about with yours, and see if there’s any difference.